Is there a way to enforce conventional commits on a squash commit to main in Bitbucket cloud?
Our repo has pre commit hooks that enforce conventional commits on a push, but we can't figure out a way to enforce conventional commits on a squash commit to main/master in the Bitbucket Cloud.
Any thoughts?
Perhaps merge checks are the answer, but I can't find any for this purpose.
